# How to select only rows that have a unique value in one column?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, distinct

Consider this example data:

```
field1  field2  
1       100  
2       100  
3       101  
4       102  
5       102  
6       103
```

I want to select only the records where the value in `field2` occurs only once. An example of the desired return data from the above would be:

```
field1  field2  
3       101  
6       103
```

How would this be done with LINQ to SQL?

--- EDIT -------
Hello all, thank you for your responses. I purposely supplied simplified data to get right to the root of my question. I think all these answers return the desired results based on my example data and I will be marking them all answers as such.

however in my real data scenario, using what I've learned from your responses, I have something like this:

```
var RefinedSource =  from a in dSource
                     group a by a.AssetID into g
                     where g.Count() == 1
                     select new
                     {
                          AssetID = g.Key,
                          AssetType = g.Min(a => a.AssetType),
                          IPInfo = AppUtility.GetIPInfo(g.Key),
                          Hostname = AppUtility.GetServerName(g.Key),
                          DeviceID = g.Min(a => a.DeviceID).ToString(),
                          Environment = AppUtility.GetSolutionAndEnvironmentNames(g.Key),
                          Manufacturer = g.Min(a => a.Manufacturer),
                          MakeModel = g.Min(a => a.MakeModel),
                          Location = g.Min(a => a.Location),
                          count = g.Count()
                     };
```

So I'm concerned about all the .min() calls... I've deduced these are necessary because of the grouping? could someone explain why these are needed? In the case of my simple example I don't see them being an issue, but with my real data there a multiple calls to min() just to be able to include all the field data I need... which doesn't seem good.

The grouping allows me to test the condition I need (that count to identify duplicate values) but how do I more directly use a condition like this but just access my real underlying data rows directly?

for example, looking at the example I just supplied above, I would like to be able to just use a.FieldName from the original "from a in dSource" part, but you can't access that after you have introduced "group by"?

again, thanks for the info, I will be marking as answers, however if anyone could explain the need for all the calls to min() (or max, or whatever) I would appreciate it, also, seeing what it looks like with my real data, is this still the way I should go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from r in tables
  group r.field2 by r.field1 into grp
  where grp.Count() == 1
  select new {grp.First(), grp.Key}
```

I'd double check that this does one SQL call. It should, and if so I'd keep it as here because `First` is a very commonly used Linq method, and when there's a few dozen equally good things to use in a given case one should favour the familiar. If it did cause more than one SQL call (again, I'd be surprised), then try `Max()` or `Min()` instead of `First()`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how it would be done in SQL (sometimes it is faster to use SQL):

```
 SELECT max(field1), field2
 FROM table
 GROUP BY field2
 HAVING count(field2) = 1
```

Example using window function in sql server 
(note, can't test right now the OVER clause might need to be in the where):

```
 SELECT COUNT() OVER(PARTITION BY field2) AS [field2Count], *
 FROM table
 WHERE [field2Count] = 1
```

Comment: Hi Hogan, thanks for the info. I would like to stick with linq to sql as my whole app is using that and I want to stay consistent. I am curious though, what if there was also a field3, field4, and field5 in the table and you needed to include all fields in your result? What would that look like? are you forced to use an aggregate function on each field to include them?

Comment: It depends on the version of SQL.  IF we are talking about SQL Server, then newest versions allow for "window functions".  This feature is also available in Oracle and some versions of progre, mysql, etc.  I'd need more detail to answer that question -- the answer I gave is standard SQL so platform/version did not matter.  (And in standard sql you can use aggregate functions to solve the problem -- it may or may not be as fast as window functions.)

Comment: I've added the standard example for using the OVER clause in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

With `LINQ` you can do simply :

```
var groups = list.GroupBy(r => r.Value).Where(grp => grp.Count() == 1);

foreach(var gr in groups){
   var field1 = gr.Key;      // KEY: is your FIELD1
   var field2 = gr.Value;    // VALUE: is your FIELD2
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that doesn't have the problem where groupings that aren't used with aggregate methods cause a separate call to the database for each item? I'm not in a position to check right now, but I'd not be sure that the engine will realise that since there's only one value per key that it can make a single call.

Comment: @JonHanna: don't have a tool on my hands now to check that, but I think it can be managed by `linq-to-sql`.

Comment: It definitely can't all the time, as I've sometimes found at inopportune times!

Comment: Hello all, thank you for your responses. I purposely supplied simplified data to get right to the root of my question. I think all these answers return the desired results based on my example data and I will be marking them all answers as such.